# RaiseError Command in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, raiseerror

So I was trying to put in a `RaisError` statement earlier today, and accidentally put it in as follows:

```
RaiseError ('Some error message', 16, -1)
```

Note the extra e.

Naturally, it threw an error, as it was meant to be `RaisError`, but what caught me off guard was the fact that in SSMS 2012, `RaiseError` was syntax-highlighted pink, as if it was a system function.  So when I was writing it, I didn't notice I added an extra e until I tried to run it.

That got me wondering what `RaiseError` was used for.  I hit up MSDN and Google trying to find some information or documentation about `RaiseError`, but I could not find anything that even hinted at its existence.  Everything I found referred to `RaisError`.

What purpose does `RaiseError` serve, and how is it used?  Is this even a thing?  Are my Google skills failing me, or is this just a bug in SSMS making an already confusing naming convention more confusing?

Comment: The color syntax highlighting in SSMS is imperfect. Recognizing pink vs. blue in this case is probably about as good as you're going to get - I don't think you'll ever get an answer from Microsoft about why the term in the form it *should* have been spelled in gets highlighted pink, never mind ever expect to see it fixed.

Comment: Understandable, but would that mean that `RaiseError` by itself isn't actually a function?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's a function.

Comment: Found some related stuff http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22661

Answer (score 0):

RaiseError was depreciated in SQL 2008, and no longer in 2012.
RaiseError was the old format of RaisError without a "()"

The Following article here mentions below: [Microsoft Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> Transact-SQL The RAISERROR (Format: RAISERROR integer string) syntax
>   is deprecated. Rewrite the statement using the current RAISERROR
>   syntax. Oldstyle RAISEERROR 164

Comment: I actually think that's a typo in the doc. Ironically.

Comment: Yes, I don't think this answer is correct. I just tried RAISEERROR (with two 'E's) in SQL Server 2005, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Right, it also doesn't work in 2000 - I proved this, then posted a screenshot with syntax errors, then shut down my VM with 2000 running. I can assure you this is merely a typo in the documentation.